# Same divs different values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm totally new to php so sorry if this is a newb question. 
I want to make an image gallery. I have all my thumbs in a thumb folder and all my full size images in a gallery folder.

My html should be like this:

```
<div class="gallery">

<div class="item">
<a href="images/gallery/img1.jpg">
<img src="images/thumb/img1.jpg>
</a>
</div>


<div class="item">
<a href="images/gallery/img2.jpg">
<img src="images/thumb/img2.jpg>
</a>
</div>
```

.........

My question is how can I use php to keep this list going for a certain amount images. Let's say 50 for example. All the images will be the same file name img1.jpg img2jpg img3.jpg....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?php
 echo '<div class="gallery">';
 for($i=1;$i<=50;$i++)
 {
    echo '<div class="item">'.
    '<a href="images/gallery/img'.$i.'.jpg">'.
    '<img src="gallery/thumb/img'.$i.'.jpg>'.
    '</a>'.
    '</div>';
 }
 echo '</div>;'
```

Comment: Whomever reverted back the changes must not know what a `code sample` should look like.

Comment: @andre3wap that might be because I was also editing :). you can format now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop to achieve this

```
<?php
 $imageno = 50;  //the number of images
 for($i=1;$i<=imageno;$i++)
 {
    echo '<div class="item">';
    echo '<a href="images/gallery/img'.$i.'.jpg">';
    echo '<img src="gallery/thumb/img'.$i.'.jpg>';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
 }
```

Comment: How different is this answer from the initial one ?

Comment: I have been typing this, but he is the first to post

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="gallery">
    <?php for($i=1; $i<=50; $i++) : ?>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="images/gallery/img<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg">
                <img src="images/thumb/img<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```